# Flume errors : Channel hdfschannel not in active set

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I get below error message when i start my flume agent:

```
    17/10/15 14:40:47 WARN conf.FlumeConfiguration: Could not configure sink  hdfssink due to: Channel hdfschannel not in active set.
org.apache.flume.conf.ConfigurationException: Channel hdfschannel not in active set.
```

it doesn't write any files to hdfs sink. below is my flume configuration file:

```
    fmp.sources = logsource
    fmp.sinks = loggersink hdfssink
    fmp.channels = loggerchannel hadfschannel

    fmp.sources.logsource.type=exec
    fmp.sources.logsource.command = tail -F /opt/gen_logs/logs/access.log

    fmp.sinks.loggersink.type=logger
    fmp.sinks.hdfssink.type=hdfs
    fmp.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.path=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/flume

    fmp.channels.loggerchannel.type=memory
    fmp.channels.loggerchannel.capacity=1000
    fmp.channels.loggerchannel.transactioncapacity=100

    fmp.channels.hdfschannel.type=file
    fmp.channels.hdfschannel.capacity=1000
    fmp.channels.hdfschannel.transactioncapacity=100

    fmp.sources.logsource.channels = hdfschannel loggerchannel
    fmp.sinks.loggersink.channel = loggerchannel
    fmp.sinks.hdfssink.channel = hdfschannel
```

Comment: what is it? I did not understand. Sorry. I am new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a channel called **hadfschannel**, and in the rest of your configuration you are referring to a channel named **hdfschannel**.

Comment: thank you for the correction. Now, i get a new error message:                        17/10/16 19:33:17 ERROR node.AbstractConfigurationProvider: Sink hdfssink has been removed due to an error during configuration
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Sink hdfssink is not connected to a channel at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:419)
 at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:98)
 at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$File

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have enough information.
You should validate this thread (accept the proposed correction) and ask a new question about this new error and with more details (logs and new configuration).

Comment: Thanks! Easy but hard to get kind of fix.